# interpolation of 3D surface in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 3 dimensional (X-Y-Z) data which includes-

11 `Y` vectors (`100*1` each (range `0:0.01:1`)) each is unique and correspond to the same `X` vector (`100*1` (range `0:0.01:1`)). Thus, `Y` can be treated as matrix with dimension `100*11`.

Different `Y` vectors correspond to different `Z` values on Z axis (11 values of `Z` ranging from `0` to `1`).

e.g. => Every value of `Z` on Z axis i.e. `Z1=0.05 ... Z11=0.95` has different `Y` vector for the same `X` vector. Thus it is like: `X-Y1-Z1`, `X-Y2-Z2`, `X-Y3-Z3...X-Y11-Z11` (`Z1` to `Z11` are fixed values like `0.05`, `0.1 ,..., 0.95` which are repeated equal to the length of `X` and `Y`).

I have already plotted this data as 11 discrete contour lines stacked one above other in 3D space using plot3 hold on. But, I want to create surface  out of it. I think I can use interpolation using `griddata` but I didn't understand how to approach this problem. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you please add the code which didn't work? Did I understood correctly, Y1 has 100 values that are not equal to Y2 ... Y11?

Comment: @Nemesis: Yes. Y1 has 100 values that are not equal to Y2...Y11. Actually I could not understand how to do it first place.That is why i didn't add code.Sorry! I explored griddata but could not understand how it is applicable.

Comment: Well, the overall usage is not clear. How do you want to combine `X` and `Y1...Y11` in a surface plot. It seems, `X` is not the vector to employ for plotting. You will need some vector with 11 elements, each specific to one of your `Y` vectors.

Comment: X is a vector with 100 elements. I can treat X as vector (Xvec=100 element) OR I can convert it into matrix like Xmatrix= repmat(X,1,11). dimension of Xmatrix= 100*11 (all columns would be same). Similarly, I can treat all Ys as separate vectors Yvec1= 100 elements, Yvec2= 100 elements...Yvec11=100 elements.  OR I can convert it into matrix like- Ymatrix=[Y1,Y2,Y3....,Y11]. Dimension of Ymatrix=100*11. Therefore, I can make dimension of Xmatrix equal to dimension of Ymatrix.